# User input shape size, then calculate using class in python

Tags: python, class, math, input, superclass

Hi I'm a beginner and this is the details to code.

Create a parent class called shape. This should have following methods inputSides() – Ask user to enter the sides of the shape. Now create subclasses for a circle, rectangle and triangle. These should include an appropriate area() method that will use the side values from the shape class.

This is what I came up with and still struggling

```
class shape():
    def __init__(self, r = None, s1 = None, s2 = None, b = None, h = None):
        self.radius = r
        self.side1 = s1
        self.side2 = s2
        self.base = b
        self.height = h
    def inputSidesC(self):
        self.radius = int(input("Enter radius: "))
        circle()
    def inputSidesR(self):
        self.side1 = int(input("Enter side 1: "))
        self.side2 = int(input("Enter side 2: "))
        rectangle()
    def inputSidesT(self):
        self.base = int(input("Enter base: "))
        self.height = int(input("Enter height: "))
        triangle()
class circle(shape):
    def __init__(self, r = None):
        self.radius = r
    def area(self):
        pi = 3.14159265359
        print("Area of circle: ", pi * (self.radius * 2))
class rectangle(shape):
    def __init__(self, s1 = None, s2 = None):
        self.side1 = s1
        self.side2 = s2
    def area(self):
        print("area of rectangle", self.side1 * self.side2)
class triangle(shape):
    def __init__(self, b = None, h = None):
        self.base = b
        self.height = h
    def area(self):
        print("Area of triangle: ", 0.5 * self.base * self.height)

c = circle()
c.inputSidesC()

r = rectangle()
r.inputSidesR()

t = triangle()
t.inputSidesT()
```

```
Enter radius: 2
Area of circle: 12.57
Enter side 1: 2
Enter side 2: 4
Area of rectangle: 8
Enter base: 2
Enter height: 4
Area of triangle: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You should work more on inheritance.You shouldn't create instances from parent into child classes.

As all of your shapes have an area attribute, let's put area calculator inside parent class.

```
class shape():
    def calculateArea(self,*args):
        a = 1
        [a:= a*i for i in args]
        return a
```

this calculate area function will multiply whatever it takes as arguments and return. This will work in more situation like rectangle, triangle etc.

```
class circle(shape):
    def __init__(self, r = None):
        self.radius = r
    def area(self):
        pi = 3.14159265359
        return self.calculateArea(float(self.radius),pi,2)
```

As you inherited from shape class, child classes can use parent class methods.

However, in some cases you would need to inherit shape class but assume that calculating an area is different than others. In this case you can override it by simple redefine method

```
class rectangle(shape):
    def __init__(self):
        self.side1 = float(input("edge 1"))
        self.side2 = float(input("edge 2"))
    def calculateArea(self):
        return self.side1 * self.side2
```

at the end, simply create instances and call methods.

```
c = circle(input("Enter Circle Radius"))
print(c.area())

r = rectangle()
print(r.calculateArea())
```